# Lightcase.js :How to show a series of images under the document ready function

Tags: javascript, lightcase.js

I am working on a project which requires me to show some images one after the other in a popup on page load. To accomplish this, I'm using [lightcase.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Versatile-Responsive-jQuery-LightBox-Plugin-lightcase-js.html) as it fulfills my requirement to a great extent. However, I don't want to load the images the way it has been shown in the demo. Rather, I want to initialize the images under the document ready function.

After googling a lot I came across a piece of code that does the job to some extent. The complete code is:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lightcase Lightbox plugin test</title>
    <link href="css/lightcase.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightcase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.events.touch.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var imgURLs = [
            'https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
             "https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage_2x.png"
          ];
          var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgURLs.length);
          var imgURL = imgURLs[randomIndex];

          setTimeout(function(){
              lightcase.start({
                href: imgURL,
                // more options like width, height, etc.
              });
           },1000); // 1000 to load it after 1 second from page load
          
        });
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see that the above code randomly loads any one image on page load. Could someone please suggest a tweak/change in the code so that it loads a series of images like a gallery plugin. Thanks.

NOTE: Lightcase Author's website is not working hence am unable to see the documentation.

Comment: Instead of using setTimeout just use a document ready event listener

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code works well by randomly showing any one image. However, my requirement is to show both images one after the other. How should I accomplish that??.